# How to find attr which has class "select"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to find attr which has classname as "select" using Javascript

```
<div class="tab_container">
    <a target="1" class="select">Leave</a>
    <a target="2">Permission</a>
    <a target="3">OT</a>
    <a target="4">Comp-Off</a>
</div>

$('.tab_container a').hasClass("select").attr('target');
```

Suggestions will be appreciated...

Comment: UM..... `$('.tab_container a.select")` Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you already have loaded jQuery, so do it like this:

```
$('.tab_container a.select').attr('target');
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `hasClass()` at all, you can simply:

```
$('.tab_container a.select').attr('target');
```

`hasClass()` returns a boolean value depending on whether an element has a class or not. You'd use `hasClass()` like this:

```
$('.tab_container a').on('click', function() {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('select') )
        ...
    else
        ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.tab_container a.select').hasClass("select").attr('target');
```

Comment: `hasClass` return boolean, so chaining `.attr` method has no sense.